# Python- MM/DD/YY Sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, date, datetime

So I'm getting this error:

```
time data '6/28/18' does not match format '%b/%d/%y'
```

I have a csv file with the 4th column having the dates and want to sort the data by date... Any suggestions or possible solutions?  I'm not so familiar with the datetime feature of Python...

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('example.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = sorted(reader, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[4], '%b/%d/%y'))

print (data)
```

Comment: use `"%m/%d/%y"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"%m/%d/%y"` instead of `"%b/%d/%y"`

```
>>> x = '6/28/18'
>>> datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y')
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 28, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `datetime.strptime` format string should be `'%m/%d/%y'`.

The `%b` option would work if your month was an abbreviated name like 'Jun'

For more on Python's datetime formatting options see this link:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior